# Web3.js and Ether.js help me

Tags: hex, byte, web3js

Im learning web3, and while examining the source code of a page, I saw that the abi file was written in a strange way, what is it? how can i decode?[image]

I assumed it was hexcode and tried to convert it..

http://ddecode.com/hexdecoder/

it didn't work

Comment: Instead of adding a screenshot can you either add a snippet of the code or the URL for the source code?

Answer (score 0):

ABIs are JSON files. JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation, and is a commonly-used data transfer format. Here's an introduction to JSON: https://www.w3schools.com/whatis/whatis_json.asp

Here's a quick description of ABIs: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/235/97038

EDIT: It appears that the file you're looking at is obfuscated: https://blog.jscrambler.com/javascript-obfuscation-the-definitive-guide